# Why can't Asian flush be treated in a similar way to lactose intolerance?

Tags: medications, genetics

I have been reading about the [Asian flush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_flush_reaction), which is caused by a [histamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histamine) reaction to a toxic byproduct of alcohol metabolism, acetaldehyde.

Some individuals are able to suppress the histamine reaction by taking histamine-blockers like [Pepcid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famotidine), but that can cause a buildup of acetaldehyde. Unfortunately, acetaldehyde is linked to higher incidence of esophageal cancer in individuals who experience Asian flush.

This made me think of Lactaid, which is a common pill taken by those who are lactose-intolerant. The Lactaid pill delivers the lactase enzyme, thereby breaking down the lactose that the person has just consumed. Lactose intolerance and [Asian flush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_flush_reaction) seem like similar issues, so why can't there be a pill that delivers [ALDH2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALDH2) to stop [Asian glow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_flush_reaction) in a healthy manner?